# problem in understanding gpg

Tags: ubuntu, git, gpg, github

now there is a project on github that I'm interested in

the project author is including his finger print and the public key in a .asc file

i want to relate things together as I new to the space

how i make use of both, the public key and the finger print, to verify the authenticity of the project

I will be cloning the repository and using the show signature flag of git

please note that i am still new to the space and would like to learn more and understand what i am doing, i am willing to have long detailed answers to dive more in this topic

i would like to know and understand the exact steps of what shall i do with the finger print and the .asc file to verify the authenticity of the cloned repository

thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Unix/Linux specific question, so it might get migrated to Cryptography or Computer Security StackExchange, or to SuperUser.SE.

You can use `gpg2 --import keyfile.asc` to import the key to your GPG. This will allow you to use the `git verify-commit` and `git verify-tag` commands to verify signatures on various elements on the cloned git repository. **But without further checking on the key itself, this only protects from accidental data corruption, not against malicious action.**

The fingerprint only relates to the key itself, not to anything in the git repository. If the fingerprint is provided along with the public key, then the fingerprint will only be useful to verify that the key itself has not been accidentally corrupted in transit. (If the key has been maliciously changed, the fingerprint provided alongside it will probably also be.)

You can use `gpg2 --show-keys keyfile.asc` to see if the key has been signed by others; if it is, the keys can be automatically verified by GPG if you have the GPG public key of the signer *and* have told GPG that you trust the signer to be careful in signing other people's keys. This can be repeated to form a "chain of trust" through as many people as you are willing to accept.

Otherwise, you'll have to contact the author of the project, and get the fingerprint from them in some way you can trust not to be tampered with. After verifying the fingerprint with `gpg2 --fingerprint <key ID>` and confirming that it matches what the owner says it should be, you can trust the key is actually from the author of the project.